# Disabling mysites after some have already been created

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem, mysite

We've been trying to disable mysites for users. When someone clicks on a user we only want them to go to the person.aspx page. We also aren't interested in anything other than displaying some properties for a user.

Some of the errors were we started receiving since is

> Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialFeedManager.GetFeedFor:
>       Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialException: 
>       No personal site exists for the current user, and no further information is available.

and

> EnsureMySiteUrl: PersonalSiteUrl of page is null!

Also for many users the `Feed service provider defined identifier:` property is still set to their previous personal site. Does this value need to be blank now?
Does changes to the `Setup My Sites` page require a crawl? What are the proper steps to resetting mysites back to a state before any personal sites were allowed to be created?